# Masking link with a 302 redirect through nginx not working

Tags: nginx, redirect, redirection

I'm trying to mask an affiliate link, so I want to have a 302 redirect through nginx

I want to redirect all `/go` links to the respective affiliate link, so all link redirects would be like `mydomain.com/go/affiliate` redirects to > `https://www.affiliatelink.com`

Right now this is what I have

```
location /go {
                rewrite ^/affiliate$ https://www.affiliatelink.com redirect; 
     }
```

I have tried everything and I cannot seem to be able to get it to work. Is there a specific file I need to do it on?

I have already tried both `/sites-enabled/default` and `/conf.d/nginx.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite doesn't work because the URL path you are requesting is `/go/affiliate` but the `rewrite` matches on the exact path `/affiliate`, which can never be found in `location /go` anyway. Fixing that is trivial and obvious, but for performance reasons you should avoid regex whenever possible.

Instead of this sort of `rewrite`, use one of two alternate approaches:

1. If you have only a few URL paths to match, use a `location` for each one:

   ```
   location /go/affiliate {
       return 302 https://affiliate.example.com/;
   }
   ```
2. If you have a large number of links, I'd say more than 7 or so, use a `map` instead.

   ```
   map $uri $aff_redirect {
       default            "";
       "/go/affiliate"    "https://affiliate.example.com/";
       # more links
   }
   ```

   A `map` goes in the `http` block outside of any `server` block.

   To use it, check for `$aff_redirect` variable in the appropriate `server` block.

   ```
   if ($aff_redirect) {
       return 302 $aff_redirect;
   }
   ```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/J2PQKpqP this is my `mydomain.com-ssl.conf`,  https://pastebin.com/HRHSW2nv this is my  main `nginx.conf `, I commented out the Map function to test the other one, but I tried both. Also tried it on the normal config and the SSL version one, since the site is using https

Comment: Finally got it to work.  I had something wrong on my main nginx.conf. I wasn't able to get it to work with a map function tho. I don't know if that was because it was inside a HTTP tag and the site is  https only. It only worked with multiple `location` tags like you described in `sites-enabled/mydomain.com-ssl.conf`, tried using the location tags in `sites-enabled/default` didn't work either